# Не могу добавить строку запроса в url

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь добавить в URL строку запроса
Чтобы было https://localhost:44390/param.aspx?login=11
листинг

```
[![string longUrl = "https://localhost:44390/param.aspx?article=1";
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(longUrl);
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
            query\["action"\] = "login";
            query\["attemps"\] = "11";
            uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
            longUrl = uriBuilder.ToString();][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string longUrl = "https://localhost:44390/param.aspx";
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(longUrl);
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
query["login"] = "11";  
uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
longUrl = uriBuilder.ToString();
```